# pgpool-II VIP azure

Tags: azure, postgresql-9.6, pgpool

I have setup pgpool-II in azure to load balance between two PostgreSQL cluster. I am using streaming replication to replicate data. Now I am planning to setup VIP so that the auto-failover is automatic. But the VIP address is not externally routable, how do I do this in azure? In AWS I can use elastic IP.

Comment: Could you show me how do you config your pgpool-II? install it on two VMs or install it on another VM? how do you setup the VIP?

Comment: I have configured pgpool-II on two machines. Would like to configure VIP as second IP on both machines. But VIP would be down on second machine. Only when there is a failover the second VM VIP is enabled. But just don’t know how we do this Azure.

Comment: just want to make them failover? for now, setup VIP is not support. As a workaround, we can use Azure public load balancer, or create  a VM and isntall HAproxy on it.

Comment: Can I use reserved IP for two VM in a resource group? Other option is to use ALB but can ALB route the request to a VM and attach it to a internal private IP address?

Comment: In Azure we can't setup one ip address to two VMs. what is mean about internal private IP address? not get from Azure? like 10.0.0.4?

Comment: Private IP address i meant is provided by Azure. Yes 10.0.0.4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157528/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-varun7447).

Comment: Yes, Azure public facing load balancer will route traffic to Azure VMs(private ip address).